# SQL: Dupe check using multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert, duplicates

I have to make a:

```
INSERT INTO aaa(DateFrom, DateTo)
SELECT DateFrom, DateTo FROM bbb
```

but sometimes this date interval already exists in aaa

How should I add the WHERE to the SELECT, to not insert in aaa if that date interval already exists

My problem is this: if I add something like:

```
WHERE bbb.DateFrom NOT IN aaa.DateFrom AND bbb.DateTo NOT IN aaa.DateTo
```

this will not check for both dates (interval), but either "From" or "To" dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert is fine,

> INSERT INTO @aaa(DateFrom, DateTo) 
>   SELECT b.DateFrom, b.DateTo  FROM @bbb
>   b

You need to get rid of your existing WHERE clause and perform a LEFT JOIN instead.

> LEFT JOIN @aaa a ON a.DateFrom =
>   b.DateFrom AND a.DateTo = b.DateTo

You can then combine this with a new WHERE clause to test for the absence of entries in the second table:

> WHERE ISNULL(a.DateFrom,'') = ''

And voila you have your query!

Fully worked example below:

> DECLARE @aaa TABLE  (   DateFrom
>   datetime, DateTo datetime )
>
> INSERT INTO @aaa(DateFrom, DateTo)
>   VALUES('01 Jan 2011','31 Jan 2011')
>   INSERT INTO @aaa(DateFrom, DateTo)
>   VALUES('01 Mar 2011','15 Mar 2011')
>
> SELECT * FROM @aaa
>
> DECLARE @bbb TABLE  (   DateFrom
>   datetime, DateTo datetime )
>
> INSERT INTO @bbb(DateFrom, DateTo)
>   VALUES('01 Jan 2011','31 Jan 2011')
>   INSERT INTO @bbb(DateFrom, DateTo)
>   VALUES('01 Mar 2011','16 Mar 2011')
>   INSERT INTO @bbb(DateFrom, DateTo)
>   VALUES('01 Feb 2011','3 Jun 2011')
>
> SELECT * FROM @bbb
>
> INSERT INTO @aaa(DateFrom, DateTo) 
>   SELECT b.DateFrom, b.DateTo  FROM @bbb
>   b LEFT JOIN @aaa a ON a.DateFrom =
>   b.DateFrom AND a.DateTo = b.DateTo
>   WHERE ISNULL(a.DateFrom,'') = ''
>
> SELECT * FROM @aaa

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need to do is change your "AND" to an "OR" and add nested select statements.

```
WHERE bbb.DateFrom NOT IN (select aaa.DateFrom from aaa) AND bbb.DateTo NOT IN (select aaa.DateTo from aaa)
```

Comment: this is not checking for the interval, what if there's a record with the same DateFrom and different DatTo ... see what i mean?

Comment: Don't think I ever understood your question...not sure I do even now.  Glad you found your answer.